# I want symbol on particular date which date added event in my app in calendar view

Tags: android, calendar

I want symbol on particular date  which date added event in my app in calendar view.
Here We can see 28-nov-2012 have same different symbol.

[image: I want to add symbol , which date we are add event in calendar View]